# HttpRequest.Files is Always Empty - Implementing Multiple File Upload

Tags: file-upload, application-pages

I have an application page in LAYOUTS in the 14 hive (SP 2010) within which I am dynamically appending HTML `<input type="file"/>` controls onto the page. Now when I try to post these files to the server to save them to a document library the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` collection is always empty.

Similar to this question: [Sharepoint webpart upload file whitout[sic] using “runat server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226612/sharepoint-webpart-upload-file-whitout-using-runat-server)

**I can not use the `<asp:FileUpload/>` control with `AllowMultiple` set to true** as there are many metadata input controls that are also being dynamically added to the page. I can not use a static amount of HTML file upload controls either; I have to add additional HTML file input controls client side.

I have found, from both the [`HttpRequest.Files Property` MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as well as various other places (like [Request.Files is Empty in a Web Forms Application](http://codepolice.net/2012/08/30/request-files-is-empty-in-a-web-forms-application/)), that the HTML `<form>` elements `encType` value must be set to `"multipart/form-data"`, which I am doing via:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
}
```

When debugging the page on post-back, the `boundary=...` section of the `Request.ContentType` value is appropriately being appended to the `"multipart/form-data"` value, but the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` collection is empty. (A nice explanation of the purpose of the `boundary` data is available in Scott Hanselman's blog post [A Back To Basics Case Study: Implementing HTTP File Upload with ASP.NET MVC including Tests and Mocks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)). You can see the behavior I'm talking about in the debugger here:

[image: HttpContext.Current.Request.Files Debug Info]

Is this something to do with how requests are being handled for the Layouts directory? Or am I just missing something? Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";`.

When you are working with Application pages you have to use `Page.Request.Files` which gives you a `HttpFileCollection` object. This contains all files from all `fileupload` controls that has the `runat="server"` attribute on the page.

Comment: Both collections are empty: `Page.Request.Files` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files`. The issue is that the input controls are dynamically added to the page client side so there is no `runat="server"` attribute. Normally in ASP.NET, the `<input type="file"/>` controls post their data to the server in a multipart request and can be accessed via the `HttpRequest.Files` collection, but this doesn't seem to be working. The documentation for `HttpRequest.Files` that I linked to above says: "The file collection is populated only when the HTTP request Content-Type value is 'multipart/form-data'."

Comment: @RJCuthbertson I have multiple working solutions where `multipart/form-data` is not anywhere on the page. If the input controls are dynamically added, by javascript I presume, what prevents you from having a javascript run afterwards which adds the `runat="server"` attribute?

Comment: Adding `runat="server"` client side doesn't do anything. It's just for the page parser, so that attribute needs to exist server side to actually have an effect.